# How to clear a setinterval when go to another controller (I do not want to do clearInterval (var))

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently in my main controller I am running a setinterval. I would like when I changed to another controller the interval is over. but I do not want to do clearInterval () on the same controller. How can I do it?

```
   .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
      var interval=setInterval(function(){
        console.log("interval")
      },3000)
      $state.go("home");
  });
```

this is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6guv9myu/

Comment: *"but I do not want to do clearInterval () on the same controller"* <- why?

Comment: You can also specify a global var interval so that you can cancel it in other controller. I have edited your jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/6guv9myu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6guv9myu/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's advisable to use Angular's `$interval` service as it

1. Is much more testable, and
2. Optionally performs a digest cycle each iteration which may be required.

You can clear the interval within the controller's `$destroy` event

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $interval) {
  var interval = $interval(function() {
    console.log("interval")
  }, 3000)

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $interval.cancel(interval)
  })

  $state.go("home")

})
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
var repeater = setInterval(function () {
 console.log("interval");
 clearInterval(repeater);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change 
    var interval= 
to
    window.interval =

now interval will be a global variable accessible from any area of javascript.
Then you may call 
    clearInterval(window.interval);
 in your other controller.